# how to calculate the bounding box enclosing a set of mysql geometries?

Tags: mysql, spatial, bounding-box

I have a mysql table containing a set of shapes. The table is defined like this:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| shapeid    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| AREA       | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PERIMETER  | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| KENPROV_   | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| KENPROV_ID | double       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PROV_NAME  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ogc_geom   | geometry     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table contain 24 shapes (records). Each shape has in "ogc_geom" the polygon defining the shape.

An example of "ogc_geom" for shapeid = 0 is:

```
POLYGON((33.99319839477539 -3.185349941253662,38.084800720214844 -3.185349941253662,38.084800720214844 5.022779941558838,33.99319839477539 5.022779941558838,33.99319839477539 -3.185349941253662))
```

How can I calculate the bounding box enclosing all the shapes?

Comment: Can you give an example of one ogc_geom?

Comment: I added an example to the question. Thanks